# get access token of google API

Tags: php, curl, google-api

I want access token from google API through client id and client secret key.
But it shows Below Error. I'm passing grant_type parameter here and if I print array here It also show me grant_type.

I have enabled **API Access** also.

Error :-

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"
}
```

Code :-

```
$url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
// $headers = array('Content-Type:Content-Type' => 'application/json');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'    
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$client_id = "asdasdasdsadadasd.apps.googleusercontent.com";
$client_secret = "Wasdadsasdadasd";
$redirect_uri = "http://localhost/test/google_drive.php";
$code = "asdasdsad";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
  'grant_type' => "authorization_code",
  'code' => $code,
  'client_id' => $client_id,
  'client_secret' => $client_secret,
  'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri
));

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

If I'm directly using curl then it also show me this error.

```
curl -d "code=AUHROISATON_CODE&client_id=CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=CLINET_SECRET&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com&grant_type=authorization_code" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

Comment: Can't really help you, I don't know curl enough.
But I can show you a project I did some months, and it worked. See the first lines for the access_token.
https://github.com/torzuoliH/cisiie_OAuth2/blob/master/event.php
This isn't exactly the same method I'm using for curl options, but I hope it will work for you :)

Comment: @Zooly. Thank you for your reply. First lines means are you taking about urlencode('authorization_code') ? line n0. 21 in your git.

Comment: From the beginning until line 31, where I decode the curl response (JSON here). Then I get the access_token in the array resulted by `json_decode`

Comment: Passing an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS means the Content-Type becomes `multipart/form-data` - not sure if that gets correctly overwritten using CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER. I’d try to remove that header, and pass `http_build_query(array(…))` to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS instead.

Comment: @CBroe. Thank you for your time. I have tried with removing header and I have passed array to http_build_query() function now it showing Code was already redeemed. So I have to got new authorization code?

Comment: Yes, the code can only be exchanged for an access token once (security reasons.)

Comment: @CBroe. Problem has been solved thank you for the reply. I solved this error just because your two suggestion. Please give answer so I can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` means the Content-Type becomes `multipart/form-data` - not sure if that gets correctly overwritten using `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`.

Try and remove that header, and pass `http_build_query(array(…))` to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` instead.

---

And yes, the `code` parameter can only be exchanged for a token once.

Answer (score 0):

This may helpful. Check this out. This is working for me.

```
$requestURL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
$postData = "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=$clientID&client_secret=$clientSecret&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com";

$headers[0] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $requestURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$responseArray = json_decode($response, TRUE);
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your code but it's not working.code parameter is missing is it mandatory or not? Because it showing me code is required error.